# How should I assume to three valuables and print them in this code block

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, 2d

```
    marks=[
     [120,0,0],
     [100,20,0],
     [100,0,20],
     [80,20,20],
     [60,40,20],
     [40,40,40],
     [20,40,60],
     [20,20,80],
     [20,0,100],
     [0,0,120]
]



for raw in marks:
     for item in raw:
          pass_mark=item
          defer_mark=item
          fail_mark=item
          print(pass_mark,defer_mark,fail_mark)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexing

```
for raw in marks:
    pass_mark=raw[0]
    defer_mark=raw[1]
    fail_mark=raw[2]
    print(pass_mark,defer_mark,fail_mark)
```

If you want short code, you can use this:

```
for raw in marks:
   print(*raw)   # pass list as args
```

Answer (score 1):

Way 1 -

```
for raw in marks:
    print(raw[0],raw[1],raw[2])
```

Way 2 -

```
for i,value in enumerate(marks):
    print(*value)
```

Way 3 -

```
for raw in marks:
    print(','.join(map(str,raw)))
```